# Change Icon in a map from JSON feature

Tags: php, json, leaflet

I have this code that load all markers in a map

```
<script>
var my_json;
var icono;

var map = L.map('map').setView([-24.376224,-65.1149885], 14);

L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
    maxZoom: 18,
    attribution: 'Map data &copy; <a href="http://openstreetmap.org">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
}).addTo(map);
```

In feature.geometry.distancia I get which Icon I need to show.
If this is smallicon or yellow

```
var smallIcon = new L.Icon({
iconUrl: 'img/marker-icon-blue.png',
iconRetinaUrl: 'img/marker-icon-2x-blue.png',

});

var yellow = new L.Icon({
 iconUrl: 'img/marker-icon-yellow.png',
iconRetinaUrl: 'img/marker-icon-2x-yellow.png',
});
```

Here I can get the value from feature.geometry.distancia and put it in a variable.

```
function onEachFeature(feature, layer) {
//console.log(feature);
var empleado="<p><strong>"+feature.properties.empleado+"</strong><br>";
var fecha=feature.properties.fecha+"<br>";
var hora=feature.properties.hora+"</p>";
icono=feature.geometry.distancia;
var popupT=empleado.concat(fecha,hora);

layer.bindPopup(popupT);
}
```

I get the information from a php page that build the json, this works ok.
I try to do the same that I do in function oneachfeature but I get an error:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: feature is not defined

```
$.getJSON('geojsondata.php', function(data) {
console.log(data);
//var iconoactual=feature.geometry.distancia;
L.geoJson(data, {
  pointToLayer: function(feature, latlng) {
    //console.log(latlng, feature);
    var iconoactual=feature.geometry.distancia;
```

Here I get the value but when I assign to icon I get an error:

> leaflet.js:7 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'popupAnchor' of undefined

```
    return L.marker(latlng, {
      icon: smallIcon
    });
  },
  onEachFeature: onEachFeature
}).addTo(map);
});
```

My JSON is

```
object      {2}
type    :   FeatureCollection
features        [1]
   0        {3}
      type  :   Feature
      geometry      {3}
         type   :   Point
         coordinates        [2]
            0   :   -65.1489465
            1   :   -24.38871095
         distancia  :   yellow
      properties        {10}
         empleado   :   test@gmail.com
         fecha  :   2019-10-14
         hora   :   15:16:00
         empleadoC  :   test@gmail.com-2019-10-14-15:16:00
```

I would like that my icon type was that in my json feature.geometry.distancia. How I can do that?
Hope someone can help me with this.
Best regards.

Comment: I was expecting an onEachFeature after L.geoJson(data .  Can you try moving onEachFeature: to be right after data?  I think the probelm is that you are not iterating through data which I assume is an array of features.

Comment: It didn't work. But I make this work like this. `code`var iconoactual=feature.geometry.distancia;
        console.log (iconoactual);
        if (iconoactual=='yellow'){
          return L.marker(latlng, {
          icon: yellow
        })
        } else {
        return L.marker(latlng, {
          icon: smallIcon
        })
        }`code`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this like this

```
L.geoJson(data, {
      pointToLayer: function(feature, latlng) {
        //console.log(latlng, feature);
        var iconoactual=feature.geometry.distancia;
        console.log (iconoactual);
        if (iconoactual=='yellow'){
          return L.marker(latlng, {
          icon: yellow
        })
        } else {
        return L.marker(latlng, {
          icon: smallIcon
        })
        }
      },
      onEachFeature: onEachFeature
    }).addTo(map);
```